# Implement generic abstract class to an interface which is generic as well

Tags: c#, .net, oop, generics, repository

I have this abstract class:

```
public abstract class Entity<T> where T : struct
{
    public T ID { get; set; }
    ... other properties for modify
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to implement this class within my IRepository. what i have tried is this:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : Entity<T> //Entity<T> doesn't make sense here i should use either T2 or what should i do?
```

Also i tried to make it work like this:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : Entity<object>
```

What is the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: Your first shout does make sense as stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint). So this is not the problem

Comment: This design is flawed. See my comment to both of the answers to understand why. Perhaps state what it is you want to achieve and there may exist a better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but the following is legal; your repository has the same generic constraint as your Entity class:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T: struct
{
    Entity<T> GetEntityById(int id);
    ...
}
```

Or the following would work, but I'm not clear on how you'd want to use `T`:

```
public interface IRepository<T,U> where T : Entity<U> where U: struct
{
    Entity<U> GetEntityById(int id);
}
```

Comment: tried your solution it worked perfectly (the second part)

Comment: however  `Entity<U> GetEntityById(int id);` was wrong. i tried  `Entity<T> GetEntityById(int id)` and worked fine.

Comment: `GetEntityById` should return `T`. That's the whole point of having T as generic parameter, otherwise `IRepository<U>` having `Entity<U> GetEntityById(int id)` would be enough.

Comment: Downvoted for the same reason as the comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53976869/4228458).

Answer (score 1):

You can define the following abstractions:

```
public abstract class Entity<TKey>
    where TKey : struct
{
    public TKey Id { get; set; }
}

public interface IRepository<TEntity, TKey>
    where TEntity : Entity<TKey>
    where TKey : struct
{
    IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll();
    TEntity GetById(TKey id);
}
```

Then as a usage, for example:

```
public class Repository<TEntity, TKey> : IRepository<TEntity, TKey>
    where TEntity : Entity<TKey>
    where TKey : struct
{
    DbContext db;
    public Repository(DbContext db)
    {
        this.db = db;
    }
    public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return db.Set<TEntity>();
    }
    public TEntity GetById(TKey id)
    {
        return db.Set<TEntity>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id.Equals(id));
    }
}
```

Comment: While this may work syntactically, semantically it has little use. The OP wants a repository which will work for any entity that satisfies a certain restriction. This repository will work for any entity whose `Id` property staifies a certain restriction (it must be a struct but why?) during `GetById`. It must satisfy another restriction during the call `GetAll()`. In other words I can close this with completely different entities (`new Repository<Order, Customer`) and clearly this breaks the whole point of the repository pattern.

Comment: @CodingYoshi **(1)** `where T : struct` is part of the answer because it's been part of the question. **(2)** Above code doesn't claim to be a real/complete implementation of a repository, but it's exactly what the OP is looking for. **(3)** Discussing about correct implementation of repository is off-topic for this question. **(4)** Theorically `Repository<Order, Customer>` is acceptable for this code, if `Order` is struct and is type of `Id` property without breaking any rule.

Comment: I agree with 1 & 4. Regarding 2: Yes but you know how the OP will use it so a good answer will state to the OP the flaw. Regarding 3: Yes and no. Thus a better approach would be to ask the OP what they are trying to achieve since this approach will eventually break the pattern.

Comment: @CodingYoshi The post is trying to solve OP's compile time error and resolve some obvious syntactical mistakes + sharing a simple example. He is not asking about repository, so discussing about repository is off-topic (while it's OK if someone wants to talk about it.) Anyway, while respecting to your opinion about disliking the answer, I disagree with your point of view and I would say the answer is not misleading at all. It's trying to answer the question which is asked by user.